# Uncountable reals in the theory

Tags: logic, model-theory, proof-theory, incompleteness

### The Question

I'm looking for a possibility to somehow **proof the "essence" of [Cantor's diagonal argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument) *within* a recursive first-order theory which is satisfied by the reals** (better: within a theory of one is saying that its standard model are the reals).

With "essence" is meant, that I want to express within the theory that the universe (i.e. the reals via standard interpretation) is uncountable.

The motivation behind this is to demonstrate [Skolem's paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem's_paradox).

As this is something I would like to explore, this question can be seen as a *literature/reference request*.

### Some Notes

Besides the technical problems of defining functions (or sequences, tupels, ...) within the theory of complete ordered fields  I'm facing Gödel's barrier. Since this very theory is complete it should not be able to express something like $x \in \mathbb{N}$ or such, which seems essential to express uncountability. At least there has to be some parts of $\mathbb{N}$ which one is able to express if stating uncountability. This leads to several possibilities:

1. Change the theory (to some which is satisfied by the reals, recursive, maybe just extend the language by a relation symbol $N$?),
2. express "the universe is uncountable" in another way, or
3. prove that it is in general not possible

and to the alternate question: **Is it possible to express uncountability in a way using $\mathbb{N}$ to a minimal amount such that the incompleteness theorem isn't effective?**

Unfortunately I'm somewhat new to that field and insofar I lack knowledge.

Thanks for any hints, literature or ideas.

Comment: How is your theory expressed, for example, as a model?

Comment: Note that unless you are using an uncountable language, you can always find some countable structure that will satisfy the same theory as the $\mathbb{R}$ (by DLS) (assuming that you are using FOL).

Comment: Ah, I was unclear: by "theory express ..." I mean: if interpreted by its standard interpretation. So this is might be the point: I want to construct a formula such that its standard interpretation states the uncountability of its universe -- but not via ZF.

Comment: @aphorisme : $\;\;\;$ Do you define "X is uncountable" by $\: |\mathbb{N}| < |\hspace{.02 in}X\hspace{.03 in}| \:$ [or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind-infinite_set) $\: |\hspace{.02 in}X\hspace{.03 in}| \not\leq |\mathbb{N} \;$? $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer :  In fact both is possible. EDIT: But it might be even harder to say something about subsets (in the standard model) if we have the reals as the universe. Even though this might as hard as to state that there is no surjection ...

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to define a first order formula $\phi$ that asserts $\exists M \ | \ M$ is uncountable. And you want that your theory proves the validity of $\phi$, is that correct?

Comment: If the above is what you mean, then it's impossible to do using only a first-order formula because first-order formulae cannot express specific sizes that are infinite.

Comment: @JonasGomes : Almost. I would like to have that $M$ is the universe.

Comment: @JoshuaBiderman : ! Do you have any reference or insight? It's not obvious to me.

Comment: I can write up a proof.

Comment: @JoshuaBiderman : This would be great! : ). A sketch might be more then enough. Even though I'm not getting the point since I could express facts about cardinalities using ZFC, or?

Comment: Never mind, I misunderstood

Comment: If you want the reals to really be the reals, so in particular have theory RCF, then no. RCF is not expressive enough. If you are just asking for the sake of asking, fix a countable model of ZF and a bijection between its universe and $\mathbb{R}$. Then look at the induced structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first-order theory that has the Reals as it's standard model is the theory of Real Closed Fields (RCF). But its not a categorical theory, which means that there are many countable, uncountable, and models of any cardinality (Lowenheim-Skolem theorem).

In order to recreate a instance of Skolem Paradox, we would need a language powerful enough to state "there is an uncountable set" (and that's of course is enough to say that the universe is uncountable) in a countable model. But the theory of RCF is not that powerful.

You could, of course, add axioms to the theory of RCF that would express the existence of a (proper) set that satisfies some PA-like axioms and call that set $\omega$. With that in hand it's possible to define the property of being "uncountable" in your theory. And of course, there would be countable models of this RCF+PA. That, I think, would be a minimal instance of Skolem Paradox in a recursive first order theory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll give it a go and will see how much PA has to be in there. By the way, do you have some insights why "RCF is not that powerful" holds for the general case, i.e. "the standard interpretation states that the universe is uncountable"? Couldn't be there any trick to derive some of PA's properties within RCF, enough, to state something about uncountability? It seems clear but I do not see a chance to proof this.

Comment: RCF is not powerful enough because we can't define $\omega$ there. I dont know how much of PA is enough to make statements about countability, but my guess is that we need PA as a whole and some other axioms to ensure that there are indeed no bijection with this proper set.